# getattr with Foreignkey and prefetch_related, cause multiple SQL queries

Tags: django, django-models

I have three Django models:

```
class One(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=5)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Two(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=5)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Three(models.Model):
    one = models.ForeignKey(One)
    two = models.ForeignKey(Two, null=True)
```

I get two functions (**EDITED**):

```
def get_one():
    instances = Three.objects.all().select_related()
    for instance in instances:
        print(getattr(instance,'one'))

def get_two():
    instances = Three.objects.all().select_related()
    for instance in instances:
        print(getattr(instance,'two'))
```

When I call get_one(), I get one.title without an additional SQL query but with get_two(), I have an additional SQL query by instance. If I delete null=True in two, It works like one.
I works with Django 1.9.5 and MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

should be `select_related` instead of prefetch related, as `prefetch_related` is used in case of reverse relations.

```
def get_one():
    instances = Three.objects.all().select_related('one')
    for instance in instances:
        print(getattr(instance,'one'))

def get_two():
    instances = Three.objects.all().select_related('two')
    for instance in instances:
        print(getattr(instance,'two'))
```

Comment: sorry for the mistake. Effectively the function is select_related. I made a mistake in transcribing the code.

Comment: I do not know if it is a BUG of Django but after checking it in several ways, effectively the call to getattr (), generates a new SQL request when the field has the null parameter to True